# How to test for a monotonic relationship between two variables, without assuming a specific functional model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spearman-rho

I'd like to test the hypothesis that there is a monotonic relationship between two variables, without assuming a specific model. What is the most robust (i.e. lowest probability of type-II error) way to do this?

I can think of a few options:

- use a linear model of untransformed data. It'll be robust enough, even if I don't think the true relationship is linear.
- look at rank-transformed data, e.g. with Spearman's rank correlation coefficient
- use some kind of resampling approach, in which the order of the dependent variable is randomly shuffled. I'm not sure what statistic to compare in this approach.

Is there a fairly standard approach to this problem?

Comment: Based on your suggestions, I'm guessing your data points are independent, and that the null hypothesis you want to test is of no association, i.e. a completely flat relationship. Linear regression with "robust" (i.e. heteroskedasticity-consistent) standard errors provides a Wald test for what you want, that is valid and efficient in large samples. It requires no assumption of true linearity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spearman's or Kendall's correlations are the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use some sort of generalize additive model, where the dependent variables are relatedto the predictors as a smooth function, like done in the gam() function in R