# Statistical modelling of outcome of an inquiry

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling

Suppose a population of dentists are sent an inquiry. A number of inquiries are filled in and sent back. Each question on the inquiry represents a certain number of points. The total number of points represents the precentage that a dentist adheres to some safety regulation. I would like to test whether there is some significant relation between the outcome of the question "how long are you employed as a dentist" versus the total number of points. Ie., I would like to test whether older/younger dentists work more or less by the rules.

I am not quite sure how I would go about testing this. I thought about checking whether the percentage over the whole sample is normally distributed, and then testing whether the percentage within an agegroup is likely to come from the same distribution, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a predictor, the answer to "How long are you employed as a dentist ?", which could be discrete or continuous depending on what types of answer you allowed; & a response, the total number of points, which can likely be treated as continuous.  Perform  analysis of variance or linear regression as appropriate (& check the assumptions).

Answer (score 1):

@Scortchi's answer will work fine if you assume a linear relationship between experience and rule-following (roughly: if dentist A has twice as much experience as dentist B, he will also follow the rules twice as much).

If this assumption is unrealistic, you could test for a monotonic relationship between experience and rules-following without assuming this specific relationship, e.g., using Spearman's or Kendall's correlation coefficient. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/how-to-test-for-a-monotonic-relationship-between-two-variables-without-assuming/).