# What is the test for association between 5 point likert scale and ordinal variable?

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, likert, association-measure

Note the likert scale is

1. very satisfied
   2.satisfied
2. Don't know
3. Unsatisfied
   5.very unsatisfied
   And the ordinal variable is anxiety:
   1.normal
   2.mild
   3.moderate
   4.severe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test for a monotonic relationship between two variables, without assuming a specific functional model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/how-to-test-for-a-monotonic-relationship-between-two-variables-without-assuming)